# Fade animation inside for-loop

Tags: ios, uiview

At least I would dream of this Animation Flow:

1. FadeIn to 50% with alpha:0.5 for 2 seconds
2. Then fadeIn to 100% with alpha:1 for 2 seconds
3. Then fade out to 0% with alpha:0 for 4 seconds

After the visible animation ends, the text for the label shall be changed and then the fade routine should start again as shown above.

I feel that this code here does not allow the step by step fade animation and the code commences too early without waiting to finish the Fade out section.

```
//A FOR Loop sets text for the _label then the Animation routine should start:

- (IBAction)startFade:(id)sender
{
    [_label setAlpha:0.f];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f
                          delay:0.f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         [_label setAlpha:1.f];
                     }

                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f
                                               delay:0.f
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              [_label setAlpha:0.f];
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];
                     }
     ];
}

// Somehow the code shall wait here for ending the visible (!!) animation in the UI
// to set a new text for _label with the FOR Loop
```

The whole issue took me some days to figure out so far.  But I am stuck here with the problem to pause the code for a while as it does not automatically wait for the visual finishing of the animation which makes it difficult for me to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that is what you are really looking for; but it meets your description:

```
- (IBAction)startFade:(id)sender {
    [_label setAlpha:0.f];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [_label setAlpha:0.5f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"1st step is done.");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [_label setAlpha:1.f];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"2nd step is done.");
            [UIView animateWithDuration:4.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
                [_label setAlpha:0.f];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                NSLog(@"3rd step is done, text will be changed.");
                // let me change the text
                [_label setText:[[NSDate date] description]];
                // let me start the animation over, welcome to my infinite loop.
                [self startFade:nil];
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can I just implement a for Loop in the las statement for adding some arrays?

Comment: where would you like to add that `for(...)` loop? and what for?

Comment: change this part `[[NSDate date] description]` with the new string you'd like to show; I added the actual time to demonstrate how the text can be replaced with some new. the comment also indicates where that supposed to be happened.

Comment: id like to add different texts to my label, which I put in a string like this  NSArray * labelText1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",nil]; These should be implemented in another Array to assign the order of the labelTexts: NSArray *textCollection = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"labelText1", @"labelText2", @"labelText3", @"labelText4", @"labelText5", @"labelText6", @"labelText7", @"labelText8", nil];